# Oracle : How to make pivot query?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have a table like this :

**Table1:**
**ID** number, **Product** varchar2, **Argument** varchar2, **Value** AnyData

When it's filled, it looks like this :

[image]

I would like to create a view such as the result is :

[image]

I tried the following query :

```
select * from 
(select ARGUMENT, VALUE from Table)
pivot 
(first(VALUE) for ARGUMENT in ('Weight','Size','First Use'))
```

I tried with both aggregating functions : First and Max.

For both of them I get the following errors :

- ORA-56902: expect aggregate function inside pivot operation.
- ORA-22950: cannot ORDER objects without MAP or ORDER method.

I do Understand both of these errors. The pivot query can work like this.

But does anyone know another way to achieve the required result please ?

Thanks.
Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use condition aggravated function to do pivot.

```
select Product,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ARGUMENT = 'Weight' THEN "VALUE" END) Weight,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ARGUMENT = 'Size' THEN "VALUE" END) Size,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ARGUMENT = 'First Use' THEN "VALUE" END) FirstUse
from 
(
    select 
        Product,
        ARGUMENT, 
        "VALUE"
    from Table
) t1
GROUP BY Product
```

If you are using the same table you can try to select table instead of subquery directly.

```
select Product,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ARGUMENT = 'Weight' THEN "VALUE" END) Weight,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ARGUMENT = 'Size' THEN "VALUE" END) Size,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ARGUMENT = 'First Use' THEN "VALUE" END) FirstUse
from Table 
GROUP BY Product
```

Comment: Why would you use a subquery?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Good point, Because I saw the question query use subquery so I intuitively use subquery